# How to synchronize Fusion Tables from Spreadsheet partially?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I have set up: Google form -> Spreadsheet -> (via script file) -> ( Fusiontable.

In fusiontables I have three columns County, Number and Geometry (kml data).
I  want to update fusion table file from spreadsheet including County and Number, but not the kml data (it contains too many characters for spreadsheet)

I've managed to sync fusiontables from spreadsheet, but it replaces everything, every column, including the kml data (with nothing on it).

Is it even possible to sync rows partially, or by columns?

Spreadsheets script file code is

```
/**
* AppsScript script to run in a Google Spreadsheet that synchronizes its
* contents with a Fusion Table by replacing all rows.
*/

// Replace with your Fusion Table's ID (from File > About this table)
var TABLE_ID = '1T89UzCsy3Kug9ZkrZMzj2BT2ncOAq6lPm5vhllRk';

// First row that has data, as opposed to header information
var FIRST_DATA_ROW = 2;

// True means the spreadsheet and table must have the same column count
var REQUIRE_SAME_COLUMNS = false;

/**
 * Replaces all rows in the Fusion Table identified by TABLE_ID with the
 * current sheet's data, starting at FIRST_DATA_ROW.
 */
function sync() {
  var tasks = FusionTables.Task.list(TABLE_ID);
  // Only run if there are no outstanding deletions or schema changes.
  if (tasks.totalItems == 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var wholeSheet = sheet.getRange('A1:B318');
    var values = wholeSheet.getValues();
    if (values.length > 1) {
      var csvBlob = Utilities.newBlob(convertToCsv_(values),
          'application/octet-stream');
      FusionTables.Table.replaceRows(TABLE_ID, csvBlob,
         { isStrict: REQUIRE_SAME_COLUMNS, startLine: FIRST_DATA_ROW - 1 });
      Logger.log('Replaced ' + values.length + ' rows');
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('Skipping row replacement because of ' + tasks.totalItems +
        ' active background task(s)');
  }
}


/**
 * Converts the spreadsheet values to a CSV string.
 * @param {Array} data The spreadsheet values.
 * @return {string} The CSV string.
 */
function convertToCsv_(data) {
  // See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section3
  var csv = '';
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      var value = data[row][col].toString();
      if (value.indexOf(',') != -1 ||
          value.indexOf('\n') != -1 ||
          value.indexOf('"') != -1) {
        // Double-quote values with commas, double quotes, or newlines
        value = '"' + value.replace(/"/g, '""') + '"';
        data[row][col] = value;
      }
    }
    // Join each row's columns and add a carriage return to end of each row
    // except the last
    if (row < data.length - 1) {
      csv += data[row].join(',') + '\r\n';
    }
    else {
      csv += data[row];
    }
  }
  return csv;
}
```

Comment: yes its possible. if you found this code, what have you tried to modify and didnt work?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `Table.replaceRows`, which is used to update the whole table. You must write sql `UPDATE` instructions using [`Query.sql`](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/query) passing specific columns and `where` clause to overwrite just the columns and rows you need.